Apply filter to only modifed files on .gitattributes
I have a project where I have a LOT of resource.json files.
Inside the json there is a category that is called "time-stamp" and it saves the last modified time of the code file.
This means that everytime that I want to commit some work I have the code file and the resource.json.
So we made this in .gitattributes to resolve our problem:
# Force LF line endings on checkout for all resource.json files.
resource.json text eol=lf
*.json text eol=lf
*.py text eol=lf

# resource.json filter=resource_json_filter

Which this filter:
[filter "resource_json_filter"]
    clean = "PowerShell -executionpolicy bypass -File ./.scripts/deploy/git/ps_fix_resource.ps1"
    smudge = "PowerShell -executionpolicy bypass -File ./.scripts/deploy/git/ps_fix_resource.ps1"

And with this ps_fix_resources-ps1:
filter sed($before,$after) { %{$_ -replace $before,$after} }
$input |sed '"actor": ".*"' '"actor": "system"'|sed '"timestamp": ".*"' '"timestamp": "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z"'|sed '"lastModificationSignature": ".*"' '"lastModificationSignature": "4a15e0122c9a955ca05b407bd9fa06810c1a05bd02f35e6ab4cc38c0654af46"'

Which removes the info that gets updated that only disturbs our commits.
However, our problem is that now we have hundred of files, and they get scanned every time even if it doesn't change anything.
Is there any way to specify in .gitattributes that only resource.json that have been updated gets passed by the filter?

All smudged files are different comparing to index. The only way for Git to compare them to index is to apply the clean filter. Hence there is no way to apply filters only to updated files — before clean filters Git considers all files updated.
